# point of instantiation and second-phase dependent name lookup, C++17 vs legacy

Tags: c++, templates, scope

I was surprised that this did not work:  [see on Compiler Explorer, with compiler version and options to match my project](https://godbolt.org/z/qschjnEWP)

```
#include <utility>

namespace N1
{

enum class E1 : char;

}

class C {
    void foo () const;

    template <typename Left, typename Right>
    auto wrapper (Left&& left, Right&& right,  const char* name) const
        {
            return xzzy (std::forward<Left>(left), std::forward<Right>(right));
        }

};

using namespace N1;

void xzzy (E1& output, int input);

void C::foo () const
{
    const int value = 17;
    E1 dest;
    xzzy (dest, value);    // wrapper can't find xzzy in this case ????
    /**/wrapper (dest, value, "value");  // ??? 
}
```

I first learned about templates when Stroustrup sent out his first whitepapers, well before any compiler implemented them.  I recall when the standards committee nailed down the semantics of name lookup, documenting *point of instantiation* and that is the context in which scope is determined; later, two-stage lookup was introduced, with the defining context used in phase 1 and the P.O.I. used in phase two.

I was searching through Cppreference for *"point of instantiation"* and I didn't find a passage defining it (I think it should be immediately before the definition of `C::foo`), but [did find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#Lookup_rules)

> - non-ADL lookup examines function declarations with external linkage that are visible from the template definition context
> - ADL examines function declarations with external linkage that are visible from either the template definition context or the template instantiation context
>
> (in other words, adding a new function declaration after template definition does not make it visible, except via ADL).

This surprised me:  was this a change made along the way, and when?

I recall making the needed functions available before the P.O.I. so that it could be used by the template, with the template defined in a header file and thus *before* these functions.  If I understand it correctly, and simply won't work anymore.

I'd really like to know *when* this change took place.  But, given that it's the case, how do you prepare for a template's needs, without messing with that type's home namespace or contriving an un-natural ordering of the definitions?  If the template is in one library (with its per-library namespace) and the type is from a different library (in a different namespace), and my application code is neither of those, I expect to "adapt" the type by providing the functions needed by the template, as part of my own code.

In general the `xzzy` will not be part of the abstract data type and isn't something universal; it's how I want it to work *here* for this specific template instantiation.  It's easy to make sure that the P.O.I. is inside a namespace, for example, that I populate with the desired function definitions that I want used.

Comment: You might take a look at section 15.10.2 of **The Design and Evolution of C++** by Bjarne Stroustrup (1994) : [15.10.2](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hS9mDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT433&lpg=PT433&dq=point+of+instantiation+design+and+evolution&source=bl&ots=xOij4k24Yj&sig=ACfU3U3RMsBD-VZBSXmi75r04XbAT-HO1g&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1ubi18qbyAhWOiOAKHSUQBCMQ6AF6BAgnEAM#v=onepage&q=point%20of%20instantiation%20design%20and%20evolution&f=false). While the rules are old, some compilers have taken a lot of time to implement them like Visual C++.

Answer (score 0):

In a template any function you want to call must be either already declared or found by ADL.
The lookup is not affected by the point of template instantiation (it is: `wrapper (dest, value, "value");`).

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup

quote:
For a non-dependent name used in a template definition, **unqualified name lookup takes place when the template definition is examined**. The binding to the declarations made at that point is not affected by declarations visible at the point of instantiation.

To let it work (found by ADL) you would need to move `xzzy` to `N1`. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4ahsGKK1a).

Comment: Yes, that's the way it is now.  I'm asking if/when it was changed, what is the history of the rules?